# PHP How do I calculate a path from a user input in a 5x5 grid?

Tags: php

Im currently making a project in PHP where it has to calculate a route on a 5x5 grid. It has to react on a user input, calculate a route and display it. The route starts in the top left and ends in the bottom right. Example: A user inputs this 'R?D?DRDD' where R means Right and D means down. It has to calculate what should be put on the question marks, and display it. In this case it should display 'RRDRDRDD'. 
I've made arrays for each row now but I'm a bit stuck at how it should calculate the route from the line of characters. I'd appreciate it if anyone can help me with this. Thanks!

Edit: This is what I have so far

```
   <?php

    $row1 = array("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5");
    $row2 = array("b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5");
    $row3 = array("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5");
    $row4 = array("d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5");
    $row5 = array("e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5");


    echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
    echo "Input: <input type='text' name='userinput'>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Calculate'>";
    echo "</form>";

    echo "Your input:";
    echo  $_POST["userinput"];

    //echo Correct Solution:
    //echo $_This_is_the_solution
?>
```

The 2 echo's I commented out should output the correct path code, like 'RRDRDRDD' as the input above. I need some help with how it should read the input and translate it into the correct route.

Sorry for the confusion, I know it's a bit weird. I tried explaining it more detailed here:

It's not a visual grid. It just has to calculate the correct route from (a1) to (e5) from the user input. So if a user inputs the code 'R?D?DRDD' it has to calculate what letter should be put on the place of the question marks, and echo it (In this case 'RRDRDRDD'). I just need some help in getting it to calculate the questionmarks into the correct letters to finish the route.

Comment: Could you please provide some code? What have you tried so far? What are the main issues in your current solution?

Comment: added the code, if you have more questions ask away :)

Comment: With RRDRDRDD we got **e4**??

Comment: You start at a1, if you follow the code it ends at e5.

Comment: Very unclear what you want. Do you mean the "user" starts at "top left" (a1) and moves according to your written commands?

Comment: well, to go from left to right, you need 4*R and from top to bottom 4*D. so count the Ds and Rs in your input string and fill up to 4 ?

Comment: Yes, it's not a visual grid. It just has to calculate the correct route from (a1) to (e5) from the user input. So if a user inputs the code 'R?D?DRDD' it has to calculate what letter should be put on the place of the question marks, and echo it.

Comment: Well, if you want to "calculate the correct route" you are talking about pathfinding and that would be "I start here and I want to end up here. Give me the steps needed to do this". But that is not what you are asking since you are saying the users will input "movement" commands?

Comment: It just has to calculate what should be put on the question marks to finish the route.

Comment: "To finish the route"? This is still not clear. Do you mean "calculate a route" or so you mean, "write the cell in which I would end up if the users commands were executed one by one"?

Comment: It has to know the correct route to put on the questionmark. So the first R in the input 'R?D?DRDD' does this: (a1)->(a2). Then it has to calculate what can be put on the questionmark to continue the userinput to the finish. So it calculates the possible routes so it knows which letters can be put on the questionmarks to get to (e5).

Comment: @Cyphyx what have you tried so far? This code just looks like the skeleton of a task.

Comment: And it's ALWASY from a1 to e5?

Comment: yes it's always from a1 to e5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get a solution without any checks, count the Rs and the Ds, as you may have 4Rs to walk from left to right and 4Ds to walk from top to down and fill the ? with it:

```
$lsUserInput    = "R?D?DRDD"; 
$lnR            = substr_count($lsUserInput, 'R');
$lnD            = substr_count($lsUserInput, 'D');
$lnMissing      = substr_count($lsUserInput, '?');
$lnSteps        = 4;
$lnRMissing     = $lnSteps - $lnR;
$lnDMissing     = $lnSteps - $lnD;
$lsResult       = preg_replace('/\?/', 'R', $lsUserInput, $lnRMissing) ;
$lsResult       = preg_replace('/\?/', 'D', $lsResult, $lnDMissing) ;
echo $lsResult ."<BR>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what you basically want is to figure out which route fulfill the users assumed route with some gaps like **"R?D?DRDD"** to get from **a1** to **e5**.

Depending on if you **know** you can get from **a1** to **e5** (there are no obstacles) or not you could do different optimizations. Of course, knowing the structure you could make it very easy by just checking the difference of the row or column of the "goal" compared to where you "are" and either go down or right depending on if you are above or to the left etc.

I would probably setup the structure in a 2D array instead to easily **move** in the **x** and **y** axis.

```
    $dataStructure = [
            ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"],
            ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"],
            ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"],
            ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5"],
            ["e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5"]
        ];

echo $dataStructure[1][2]; // b3
```

A more general solution is to do pathfinding using any of the well-established pathfinding algorithms and then check which path, if any, matches the user's input.
If parts of the path is **known** then pathfinding only from the end of the known path to the beginning of the next known path would be needed in order to optimize this approach.

Comment: Yes you got it, there are no obstacles. It just has to fill in the gaps. Sorry for my weird explanations haha. I'm going to look into your solution. Thanks!